# Why isn't nitrogen a n-type dopant?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

n-type dopants are ones that have 5 valence electrons, so theoretically any of the electrons that are in that column on the periodic table should be able to increase the electron carriers in a semi-conductor. Why then is nitrogen not considered an n-type dopant?

Comment: It all depends on which material you are doping?

Comment: Let's say silicon for now, but how would the answer change based on the material?

Comment: Nitrogen does not have an electronic energy level at the right place in the gap in silicon. Just the way it goes.